# What minimum hardware watchdog device timeout is considered safe?

Tags: kernel, watchdog

I've recently setup `watchdog` using Intel hardware TCO that does automatically reboot the system it crashes (using Ubuntu LTS).

In `watchdog.conf` you can configure a timeout before reboot.

Defaults to 60secs.

Since my devices are playing audio in store which can be really problematic when there is a crash (sound gets stuck in a loop!). I'd like to know how low I could go?

I've used the default `in_memory=true` and `realtime=true`.

Thanks!

Comment: What is crashing so that sound gets looped?

Comment: It's a total system freeze from a kernel panic, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/884099/troobleshoot-16-04-inexplicable-total-system-freeze-4-hours-after-reboot-on-seve